Family Guy - Throat Clearing Madness?
Which Family Guy episode has three English guys, hidden behind newspapers and sitting in armchairs, who start to clear their throats but the throat-clearing intensifies progressively to the point of madness?

Hi and welcome to M&TV. Have you searched for this first? Just Googling the first 4 words of your title seems to lead to the episode quite easily.

This is the S08E07 of Family Guy, titled as Jerome Is the New Black.
From here

When his friends start talking about the absence of Cleveland Brown, Peter says that without a black guy, they're as boring as the London Gentleman's Club. During the drawn-out sequence showing the club's actions, all they do is read newspapers and clear their throats, gradually getting louder and louder.

Here's a YouTube video for this.



